# use resources property file on javascript

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am writing spring boot Web app using thymeleaf. I am doing client side validation on js file. I want to pull message from properties file for appropriate error message to display and and also for internalization.

Is there any way I can use resource property file on js file.

Answer (score 0):

You can read **properties file** in js file using the **messageResource.js** library (see [GitHub](https://github.com/suhaibkhan/messageResource.js)).

This code should work fine:

```
<script src="messageResource.min.js"></script>
<script>
messageResource.init({
  // path to directory containing resource files(.properties files),
  filePath : 'path/folder/'
});

messageResource.load('moduleName', function() {
  var value = messageResource.get('key', 'moduleName', 'en_US');
  console.log(value)
}, 'en_US'); 

</script>
```

I hope this is what you like to achieve so let me know if it works `:)`

Comment: is working only if I use get inside callback function. Is this how it works ?

Comment: Yeah that should be the most effective method @user8710021 :)

Comment: I don't like the way all code should be done inside callback method.